# 2D array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have written the following code for creating a 2D array and filing the first element of each row. I am new to numpy. Is there a better way to do this?

```
y=np.zeros(N*T1).reshape(N,T1)
x = np.linspace(0,L,num = N)

for k in range(0,N):
    y[k][0] = np.sin(PI*x[k]/L)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since `numpy` vectorizes operations, you can just do:

```
y[:,0] = np.sin(np.pi * x / L)
```

Note that `y[:,0]` grabs the first column of `y` (the `:` in the first coordinate essentially means "grab all rows", and the 0 in the second coordinate means "from the column at index 0" (ie the first column)). Since `np.sin(np.pi * x / L)` is also an array, you can assign the latter to the former directly.

Answer (score 2):

This question is rather for codereview@stackexchange, but this snippet works!

```
import numpy as np

N = 1000 # arbitrary
T1 = 1000 # arbitrary
L = 10 # arbitrary

x = np.linspace(0,L,num = N)

# you don't need reshape here, give the size as a tuple!
y = np.zeros((N,T1)) 

# use a vectorized call here:
y[:,0] = np.sin(np.pi*x/L)
```